# How do I write this symbol in latex

Tags: symbols, characters

Please, how do I represent this symbol in latex? I have checked [here](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html) but I could not find it.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have no idea then run http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html and insert your symbol with the mouse as perfect as you can:

[image]

Then you'll see on the right the solutions. You can also run in a terminal `texdoc comprehensive` -> page 25

Comment: If you were trying to draw a tick, you're missing four legs. :)